# When an item is created in a list, get link to item (in WebViewList mode)

Tags: sharepoint-online, power-automate, microsoft-lists

Using the SharePoint connector action:

[When an item is created](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/sharepointonline/#when-an-item-is-created)

It is possible to get a dynamic value named:

`Link to item`

You can then, for example, use this link in a notification email.

By default, the format of the URL is:

```
https://tenant_name.sharepoint.com/sites/site_name/_layouts/15/listform.aspx?PageType=4&ListId=GUID&ID=XXXX&ContentTypeID=0xlong_value_here
```

Is it possible to somehow create a link to the item so that it includes the `?env=WebViewList` query parameter.

That parameter, when added to the end of a list URL makes the list look better, eg:

```
https://tenant_name.sharepoint.com/sites/site_name/Lists/ListName/My%20View.aspx?env=WebViewList
```

As the user submits an entry via this interface, I would like to keep the user experience consistent when they click on a link to view a list item.

(Ideally, when clicking on a link to the item, I would like the item to be displayed as it is when double clicking on a list item in a list when viewing it in `WebViewList` mode).

Comment: Did you try appending `&env=WebViewList` to "Link to item" using `concat()` function in flow expression? Else you can try building URL in this format: `<siteUrl>/Lists/Tasks/DispForm.aspx?ID=1&env=WebViewList`

Comment: Did you try this suggestion, is it working for you?

Answer (score 0):

I have made the following test with the trigger When a file is created, select the dynamic content Link to item in the email body, when I receive the email, the email could be opened by clicking the link.
[image]

Comment: Is there any update on this thread? Comment here if you still need any help.